# Difference of the value in the same column with two selected filters in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to get the delta of values (*Sales Qty*) with respect to a filter (*Report No in below table*).

```
Report No    Customer    Sales Qty
Report 1     Customer A   50
Report 1     Customer B   100
Report 1     Customer C   20
Report 2     Customer A   250
Report 2     Customer B   200
```

Then I created a Slicer for Report No (Named as New) and a table containing same elements in Report No (Named as Old).

Later on with a DAX function:

```
Delta = 
var New = MAX('Database'[Report No])
var Old = max('Table'[Report No])
return CALCULATE(SUM('Database'[Sales Qty]);'Database'[Report No]=New) - CALCULATE(SUM('Database'[Sales Qty]);'Database'[Report No]=Old)
```

The function is giving the result but since Customer C is not included in Report 2, it's not showing -20 for that. Is it possible to edit Dax formula to include Customer C as well and show it -20?

Added a image presentation as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubxpV.png)